# Passing Gibbon (Mailchimp) error from service to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Mailchimp (via the [Gibbon gem](https://github.com/amro/gibbon)) to add email addresses to my Mailchimp mailing list, and I want to handle any errors that are returned by Mailchimp and display them in my view.

Here is my `Pages` controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def subscribe
        email = subscriber_params[:email]
        if email.empty?
            flash[:error] = 'Please provide an email.'
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            subscriber = Mailchimp.new.upsert(email)
            if subscriber
                flash[:success] = 'You\'re in!'
                redirect_to root_path(subscribed: :true)
            else
                # Return error coming from Mailchimp (i.e. Gibbon::MailChimpError)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And here is the `app > services > mailchimp.rb` file I set up to separate out the Mailchimp logic:

```
class Mailchimp

  def initialize
    @gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: Rails.application.credentials.mailchimp[:api_key])
    @list_id = Rails.application.credentials.mailchimp[:list_id]
  end

  def upsert(email)
    begin
      @gibbon.lists(@list_id).members.create(
      body: {
        email_address: email,
        status: "subscribed"
      }
    )
    rescue Gibbon::MailChimpError => e #This is at the bottom of the Gibbon README
      raise e.detail
    end
  end

end
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to return/send `Gibbon::MailChimpError` back to my `Pages#subscribe` action. I see it being outputted as a `RuntimeError` in my console, but I'm not sure the right way to access/pass it along.

And please let me know if there's a better practice for this kind of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the begin/rescue block to the `subscribe` action inside your controller to handle the error from there, or even better, you can use [rescue_from](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) in your controller like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from Gibbon::MailChimpError do |e|
   # Handle the exception however you want
  end

  def subscribe
   # ....
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there not a way to do it when I have the Gibbon logic in a separate service file? Also, can you explain why `rescue_from` is better than just putting it in the controller action directly?

Comment: @SpencerK. The only thing I could think of is to return `false` within the rescue block & handle that from the action. On the `rescue_from` part, I actually find it better to use that from within the parent controller, which is `ApplicationController` in your case to handle general errors to keep the DRY concept, however, in this case I can only say it's going to keep your code cleaner, as you're handling a very specific error.